# Setting up Laravel Homestead with existing project - Laravel commands not recognized

Tags: laravel, homestead

I am setting up homestead on my mac.

I have made sure that the settings are right on my storage folder. 
I have installed composer on the vagrant box.
If I navigate to /home/vagrant/Code then my code is there.

Here is my yaml file:

```
folders:
- map: ~/Sites/MYAPP/
  to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
- map: my.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/public
```

The output is just the standard "Something went wrong"

The console log shows a 500 error with a failure to load resource.

Am I doing something wrong?

I want to see the errors, so where is the .env file to turn those on?

Do I need to touch the Homestead.yaml file on vagrant?

What level of the structure does the "folders" portion of the yaml file need to be set to? Is the folder level that houses the entire laravel application? The public folder?

Is there a full explanation somewhere of all the parameters involved in setting this up? - Especially a postgres database?

Update :

Echoing out a "here" in the index.php function worked, but using a dd() produced an error - Call to undefined function dd().

It appears that the vagrant machine is not recognizing Laravel commands. Any suggestions?

Second Update:

Well, I got it working. How? I am not sure. The .env file was misnamed to .env.example so I changed that, but it didn't seem to do anything. I added homestead to the composer file - as that was mentioned in some forums but no in the install docs - and nothing seemed to happen. Then, it just started working. Frustrating.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question exactly, what is not working ?

Comment: Sorry, fixed that. Standard 500 error or nothing.

Comment: If you dd() in your index do you get there?

Comment: It gets to the index, but does not recognize dd as a function.

Answer (score 0):

Your yaml is wrong. Should look like this..

```
folders:
- map: ~/Sites
  to: /home/vagrant/Sites

sites:
- map: my.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Sites/MYAPP/public
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to restart your Vagrantbox with the --provision flag and see if that helps.

If not, try changing the APP_DEBUG to true in your .env if you haven't already to see if you get some kind of stack-trace that can help you further.

Otherwise you should try placing dd() och log in the public/index.php to see how far it's running and if you can locate what's failing that way.

Comment: I was able to output text from the index.php through an echo command. However, the dd() caused a failure - Call to undefined function dd(). Seems like laravel isn't loaded properly?

Where is the .env file? On vagrant?

Comment: The .env file is located att the root of the project, might be that it's named "example.env", in that case, rename it to .env and set the debug variable.

You should also try running composer install in the project. 

One more thing, try running php artisan to see if that works, otherwise it could be something wrong with the installation

Comment: The .env was actually named .env.example. Changed that and saw no difference. I looked at the ~/.composer/vendor/bin file on the vagrant machine and saw that it has envoy and laravel. Does that need anything else?